# ios updating view after it disappeared

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I think there is a simple answer to this question, but I can't seem to find it.

I have a view that I would like to keep updated, even after it disappears. It's a music player so it would be nice to be able to go back to the player and see the current track/art/progress without it having to update after the view loads.

I have a strong reference to the view, so it doesn't fully reload, but I can't seem to make updates to the UI elements anywhere outside the view. I have a class that is calling this, but it's completely ignored:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [playerViewController updateAlbumArt];
  [playerViewController updateSongTitle];
  [playerViewController updateSongArtist];
});
```

Is there some way to keep a view updated in the background from another class? Similar to how if a track changes on your iPhone music app, you go to the now playing screen and you see the current song progress/information without any lag or loading period.

Comment: As you don't need to update any of these visuals until just before the user returns to the view wouldn't it make sense to do the actual changes in the view's controllers viewWillAppear?

Comment: Like nickfalk. This is really ideal.  Why makes updates to a UI no one can see?  Those elements most likely won't redraw themselves because they are not visible. viewWillAppear is the correct place for this update.

Comment: Sorry, guys, I knew it was simple. Thank you.

Comment: Hm, that delay is still there. I should be calling these updates on the main queue right?

Comment: Nevermind, the reason for the lag is because of some CGI stuff that I'm performing for the album art. `viewWillAppear` was perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

viewWillAppear is your friend here.  You should probably also avoid keeping a strong reference to the originating view controller as that could result in a retain cycle.  Keep a weak reference to the parent from the child or consider creating a protocol and set the parent as the child's delegate (weakly referenced). And have the child communicate changes to the parent via the delegate reference.